# Is it possible to connect a Linux server like (10.162.120.200) from web tool using javascript? If so, please provide an example

Tags: javascript

i want to connect a linux server from a web application.

```
<script>
  document
    .getElementById("Start")
    .addEventListener("click", function(  ){ 
        return confirm("A to B traffic resumed") ;
    });
</script>

<script>
  document
    .getElementById("Stop")
    .addEventListener("click", function(  ){ 
        return confirm("A to B traffic stopped") ;
    });
</script>
```

Button : start 
Function should be : go to linux server and connect with it's id and password.
then start some process

Button : Stop
Function should be : go to linux server and connect with it's id and password.
then stop some process

Comment: You don't need JavaScript if you use a form to post to the given IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need some service running on the Linux host to handle HTTP requests and do whatever action you want.  Since you already know some JavaScript, look into Node.js for this.

Answer (score 0):

This in fact is decided by your server side appliction.
A typical scenario is: when user clicks a button at client side (in the browser),  javascript code (you can use jquery or other tech) sends a request (e.g., "kill process xxx") to the server.  The web server app(maybe a java servlet or asp.net app or php app) processes the request and start/stop the process on the server and sends the result back to javascript client.